# Why Isn't My Clear Style Preventing Sibling Element From Floating?

Tags: css, css-float

I have an extremely simple snippet of HTML/CSS:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 180px; clear: both;">Foo</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 180px;">Bar</div>
```

Both divs float left, but the Foo div has clear: both.  That should prevent the Bar div from floating next to it ... but it doesn't.  If you throw that HTML into a browser you'll see the two divs are adjacent.

What am I failing to understand about clear?

Comment: because Bar should clear the float before it ... we don't clear the float after but before

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use

Comment: That doesn't make sense: if `clear` only clears the float in front of it, why are there `clear: left`, `clear: right`, and `clear: both` styles?

Comment: we talk about DOM structure ... clear will clear the float elements that are *before* in the DOM .. so you need to add the clear to Bar and it will work like you want https://jsfiddle.net/2dkvo14m/

Comment: concerning left/right/both it depend on the float you want to clear .. actually you are using only `float:left` so you can use `clear:both` or simply `clear:left`

Comment: Strange, I've been using floats and clears for years an always thought `clear:left` = "prevent elements from floating to the left" and `clear: right` = "prevent elements from floating to the right.  But clearly I misunderstood.  If you want to put something to the effect of "clear only applies to elements that came before the current element in the DOM" I'll happily accept it.

Comment: `The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements` --> notice the use of *that precede it* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: and a bit down in the same doc `left
Is a keyword indicating that the element is moved down to clear past left floats.` --> notice the *past left floats*

Comment: So what you said is almost good but you simply missed the fact that it will not apply to the future elements but the actual one considering the previous elements

Comment: Man, Stack Overflow is about answers, not comments :)

Comment: Well I consider these as comments because the real answers are in the duplicate links ;) you will find a more detailed explanation there and also in the Doc

Comment: Those other questions are hardly duplicates.  Not quite getting that the `clear` property is DOM order-dependent is completely different from not understanding why a container full of floated elements has no height.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to run clear after **Foo**, you want to run it before the start of **Bar**

```
<div style="float: left; width: 180px;">Foo</div>

<div style="clear: both; float: left; width: 180px;">Bar</div>
```

The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Before I accept it, could you please edit it to add just a little bit more about *why* I need to move the clear to the second element?  Because my question wasn't really "how do I make things float together", it was "why aren't these things floating together"?  Temani Afif explained it in the comments, but those might easily be missed by someone visiting this page later on.